# Tomcat instances on newly added node can't start with SSL

Tags: tomcat7

> exception:
>   "java.lang.Exception: Connector attribute SSLCertificateFile must be defined when using SSL with APR"

I have found that this error is because of a missing APR library which has to be manually installed:

> "The APR is a native library that you may install during Tomcat installation."

So this library is probably missing on newly installed Tomcat instances (czchols3883/czstlls346).

When I commented out the line in server.xml with APR listener:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
```

Tomcat started correctly! So looks like the issue is really caused by this missing library.

Please could you check it out and install the missing library on new nodes rh6.5 and tomcat 7.0.59?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that you want to use SSL you will need a certificate and a key file. This shows your the message.

I point you to the latest doc as I don't know which Tomcat version your use.

[http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-*Connector*-*APR/Native*(deprecated)](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_Connector_-_APR/Native_(deprecated))

You have to options now, as far as I see.

1.) Don't use apr.
2.) Provide a SSLCertificateFile to the config file.

Comment: hi we are using 7.0.59 tomcat version

Comment: Okay. Then take a look into that doc, but there are more or less the same options and requirements. Solution options are the same as written in the answer